# Error linking SDL3 project undefined reference to `__imp_glCreateShader'

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I have simple project for tests. But I can't build the project successfully with **MinGW64**.
The project consists of CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

set(PROJECT "GLTest")

set(THIRD_PARTY_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/3rd-party")

set(glm_INSTALL_DIR ${THIRD_PARTY_DIR}/glm)
set(sdl3_INSTALL_DIR ${THIRD_PARTY_DIR}/sdl3)

if (${PREBUILD_SOLUTION})
    project(THIRD_PARTY NONE)

    include(${THIRD_PARTY_DIR}/cmake/glm.cmake)
    include(${THIRD_PARTY_DIR}/cmake/sdl3.cmake)

    return()
else()
    project(${PROJECT})
endif()

enable_language(C)
enable_language(CXX)
enable_language(ASM_NASM)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT  win64)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER> <INCLUDES> \
<FLAGS> -f ${CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT} -o <OBJECT> <SOURCE>")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS off)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on)

if(MSVC)
  #add_compile_options(/W4 /WX)
else()
  #add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic )#-Werror)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DGLTEST_DEBUG")

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${THIRD_PARTY_DIR}/sdl3")

find_package(SDL3 REQUIRED SDL3)
find_package(OpenGL 4 REQUIRED OpenGL)

add_executable(${PROJECT} main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT} PRIVATE
        ${SDL3_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} PRIVATE
        SDL3::SDL3-static
        OpenGL::GL
        OpenGL::GLU
)
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <SDL3/SDL.h>
#include <SDL3/SDL_opengl.h>


typedef float t_mat4x4[16];

static inline void mat4x4_ortho( t_mat4x4 out, float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float znear, float zfar )
{
    #define T(a, b) (a * 4 + b)

    out[T(0,0)] = 2.0f / (right - left);
    out[T(0,1)] = 0.0f;
    out[T(0,2)] = 0.0f;
    out[T(0,3)] = 0.0f;

    out[T(1,1)] = 2.0f / (top - bottom);
    out[T(1,0)] = 0.0f;
    out[T(1,2)] = 0.0f;
    out[T(1,3)] = 0.0f;

    out[T(2,2)] = -2.0f / (zfar - znear);
    out[T(2,0)] = 0.0f;
    out[T(2,1)] = 0.0f;
    out[T(2,3)] = 0.0f;

    out[T(3,0)] = -(right + left) / (right - left);
    out[T(3,1)] = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    out[T(3,2)] = -(zfar + znear) / (zfar - znear);
    out[T(3,3)] = 1.0f;

    #undef T
}

static const char * vertex_shader =
    "#version 130\n"
    "in vec2 i_position;\n"
    "in vec4 i_color;\n"
    "out vec4 v_color;\n"
    "uniform mat4 u_projection_matrix;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "    v_color = i_color;\n"
    "    gl_Position = u_projection_matrix * vec4( i_position, 0.0, 1.0 );\n"
    "}\n";

static const char * fragment_shader =
    "#version 130\n"
    "in vec4 v_color;\n"
    "out vec4 o_color;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "    o_color = v_color;\n"
    "}\n";

typedef enum t_attrib_id
{
    attrib_position,
    attrib_color
} t_attrib_id;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8 );

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 5 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );

    static const int width = 800;
    static const int height = 600;

    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow( "", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext( window );

    GLuint vs, fs, program;

    vs = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
    fs = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );

    int length = strlen( vertex_shader );
    glShaderSource( vs, 1, ( const GLchar ** )&vertex_shader, &length );
    glCompileShader( vs );

    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv( vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if( status == GL_FALSE )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "vertex shader compilation failed\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    length = strlen( fragment_shader );
    glShaderSource( fs, 1, ( const GLchar ** )&fragment_shader, &length );
    glCompileShader( fs );

    glGetShaderiv( fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
    if( status == GL_FALSE )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "fragment shader compilation failed\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader( program, vs );
    glAttachShader( program, fs );

    glBindAttribLocation( program, attrib_position, "i_position" );
    glBindAttribLocation( program, attrib_color, "i_color" );
    glLinkProgram( program );

    glUseProgram( program );

    glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glClearColor( 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

    GLuint vao, vbo;

    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray( attrib_position );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray( attrib_color );

    glVertexAttribPointer( attrib_color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( float ) * 6, 0 );
    glVertexAttribPointer( attrib_position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof( float ) * 6, ( void * )(4 * sizeof(float)) );

    const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    /*  R, G, B, A, X, Y  */
        1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 1, width, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 1, width, height,

        1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 1, width, height,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 0, height
    };

    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( g_vertex_buffer_data ), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    t_mat4x4 projection_matrix;
    mat4x4_ortho( projection_matrix, 0.0f, (float)width, (float)height, 0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f );
    glUniformMatrix4fv( glGetUniformLocation( program, "u_projection_matrix" ), 1, GL_FALSE, projection_matrix );

    for( ;; )
    {
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        SDL_Event event;
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {
            switch( event.type )
            {
                case SDL_KEYUP:
                    if( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE )
                        return 0;
                    break;
            }
        }

        glBindVertexArray( vao );
        glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6 );

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow( window );
        SDL_Delay( 1 );
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext( context );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to build a project, I get a linking error `undefined reference to __imp_glCreateShader"`. I've looked all over the Internet. But I have not found an answer to my question. Maybe someone has faced a similar problem?

---

UPD:

Build command

```
[build] cmd.exe /C "cd . && F:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g -DGLTEST_DEBUG  CMakeFiles/GLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj -o GLTest.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libGLTest.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  ../3rd-party/sdl3/lib/libSDL3.dll.a  -lopengl32  -lglu32  -lopengl32  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
```

Error message

```
[build] cmd.exe /C "cd . && F:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g -DGLTEST_DEBUG  CMakeFiles/GLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj -o GLTest.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libGLTest.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  ../3rd-party/sdl3/lib/libSDL3.dll.a  -lopengl32  -lglu32  -lopengl32  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/GLTest.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `main':
[build] F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:85: undefined reference to `__imp_glCreateShader'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:86: undefined reference to `__imp_glCreateShader'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:89: undefined reference to `__imp_glShaderSource'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:90: undefined reference to `__imp_glCompileShader'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:93: undefined reference to `__imp_glGetShaderiv'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:101: undefined reference to `__imp_glShaderSource'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:102: undefined reference to `__imp_glCompileShader'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:104: undefined reference to `__imp_glGetShaderiv'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:111: undefined reference to `__imp_glCreateProgram'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:112: undefined reference to `__imp_glAttachShader'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:113: undefined reference to `__imp_glAttachShader'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:115: undefined reference to `__imp_glBindAttribLocation'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:116: undefined reference to `__imp_glBindAttribLocation'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:117: undefined reference to `__imp_glLinkProgram'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:119: undefined reference to `__imp_glUseProgram'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:127: undefined reference to `__imp_glGenVertexArrays'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:128: undefined reference to `__imp_glGenBuffers'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:129: undefined reference to `__imp_glBindVertexArray'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:130: undefined reference to `__imp_glBindBuffer'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:132: undefined reference to `__imp_glEnableVertexAttribArray'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:133: undefined reference to `__imp_glEnableVertexAttribArray'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:135: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertexAttribPointer'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:136: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertexAttribPointer'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:149: undefined reference to `__imp_glBufferData'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:153: undefined reference to `__imp_glGetUniformLocation'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:153: undefined reference to `__imp_glUniformMatrix4fv'
[build] F:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: F:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/main.cpp:171: undefined reference to `__imp_glBindVertexArray'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[proc] The command: "F:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build f:/VSCodeProject/GLTest/build --config Debug --target all -- exited with code: 1 and signal: null
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please, post **complete** error message. It should include the source/object file which uses the symbol, which is undefined. Also, add to the question post the exact command line used for linking. You could obtain that command line by running `mingw32-make` with additional option `VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Updated my question. Output from Visual Studio Code

Comment: Windows `opengl32` doesn't export any function above GL 1.2; every other function is considered 'extension' and have to be loaded at runtime via `wglGetProcAddress` (or `SDL_GL_GetProcAddress`). There are some specialised extension loader libraries like GLEW if you don't want to do that yourself.